# When does exactly garbage collector kicks in at Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm running a Memgraph Platform and I have about 600 000 nodes and relations it my graph. I cleared the database using `MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE(n)` but the release of the memory is not instant. I can see that after some time (few dozen of seconds) the memory is freed. Can I some how make this faster?

How often is garbage collector run in Memgraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the worst case scenario garbage collector should free it after a 30 seconds. This time interval can be configured [using the flag](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/next/reference-guide/configuration#storage) `--storage-gc-cycle-sec`. 30 is the default value.

Comment: I dont think its working. even I had same issue. I posted on the discord channel looks like its a bug on memgraph